# Blue Prism - is find Wait for Document Loaded available for Chrome?

Tags: html, blueprism

I'm using BP 6.5, with new Browser Automation mode, and I see that it's missing some functionalities which was available for HTML mode. The most important for me is missing "Wait for Parent Document Loaded" - there's only Check Exists available.

Is it me doing sth wrong, or this is the only wait available for Browser mode? Is there a work around?
(Check Exists can work for most scenarios, but seems useless:

- if page is refreshing automatically, after choosing some option from Combo,
- Navigating to "Next page", reading HTML table, where most objects remains the same, and it's not possible to say which values are likely to be changed, etc)

[image]

Comment: I don't think Chrome is supported in 6.5. If memory serves me right, it is supported in 6.6

Comment: Chrome is supported from v6.4 of BluePrism. However that 'support' is pretty limited. I have the same issue that the it's not possible to use a Wait stage to check if the document has loaded.

Comment: I did some initial experiments, and I think Check Exists may wait for document loaded. It still needs to be confirmed, though.

Answer (score 1):

The following still has to be extensively tested, but i try to help you.

**SHORT ANSWER - MANUAL WAY & EXPLANATION:**

Insert the following JavaScript to a mapped HTML tag, which always exists in a current page (html tag = HTML). This will create an element in the header. (Navigate stage > Insert JavaScript Fragment)

```
function CreateLoadedElement(){var LOADED = document.createElement("ChromePageLoadedForBluePrism");document.head.appendChild(LOADED);}
```

[image]

Now insert another one which will trigger this function when the document is loaded:

```
"window.onload = CreateLoadedElement();"
```

Now you need to have another element in the Application Modeller, which you are creating a waiting stage, which is waiting for this element to exists.

***Due to that this element will be created only, when the document is loaded, therefore that element will held the Waiting stage correctly.***

---

**OR**

---

**LONG ANSWER - COPY ELEMENT WAY:**

Follow the following steps:

**STEP1:**

Create the following element (HTML - Loaded) in Application Modeller:

[image: Web element type = CHROMEPAGELOADEDFORBLUEPRISM]

Web Element Type = CHROMEPAGELOADEDFORBLUEPRISM 
Match Index = 1

This element will be created by the JavaScript code in Stage Insert JS Page Loaded (Step 3), when the document loads.

**STEP 2**:

Create the following element (HTML - Html Root) in Application Modeller:
[image]

This an element what the page will interact also.

**STEP 3:**

Copy the following code and insert it as **Page** to your **Object**.

```
<process name="__selection__Software - Chrome Template" type="object">
  <subsheet subsheetid="55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd" type="Normal" published="True">
    <name>Wait Until Loads</name>
    <view>
      <camerax>0</camerax>
      <cameray>48</cameray>
      <zoom version="2">1.25</zoom>
    </view>
  </subsheet>
  <stage stageid="063b8761-58b3-47fd-aee8-f6ecb45e5d23" name="Wait Until Loads" type="SubSheetInfo">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <narrative>Waits until the page is loaded. In case of time out throws exception.</narrative>
    <display x="-195" y="-90" w="150" h="60" />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="fdfe5291-d54c-482a-87fa-b387430d3deb" name="End" type="End">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="-45" y="195" />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="ff35742e-c8f1-4876-9bfd-ab378be3e216" name="Input" type="Block">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="-270" y="-45" w="150" h="75" />
    <font family="Segoe UI" size="10" style="Regular" color="7FB2E5" />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="d8fba2e4-33d9-468f-80f1-59557058231e" name="Start" type="Start">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <preconditions>
      <condition narrative="IE winodw is open and attached" />
      <condition narrative="The page is not a blank page (about:blank)" />
    </preconditions>
    <postconditions>
      <condition narrative="Page is loaded" />
    </postconditions>
    <display x="-45" y="-105" />
    <inputs>
      <input type="text" name="Parent URL" narrative="Page is to be loaded. Wildcard is allowed. First found will be chosen." stage="Parent URL" />
    </inputs>
    <onsuccess>23533afe-6d7c-48ff-b53a-8eb647519e0f</onsuccess>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="c1d43556-4b3a-46eb-b08d-0cb1967a9c63" name="Parent URL" type="Data">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <display x="-195" y="-15" w="150" h="30" />
    <datatype>text</datatype>
    <initialvalue xml:space="preserve">*</initialvalue>
    <private />
    <alwaysinit />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="fedb22ad-bcf0-44b7-b117-bcd8f937c72d" name="Go" type="WaitEnd">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="-30" y="-45" w="30" h="30" />
    <onsuccess>525c998c-dd0d-40a4-bdf0-fc3b94816f3e</onsuccess>
    <groupid>ddb7d93e-1817-4d88-99a1-7639b8e6fa77</groupid>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="23533afe-6d7c-48ff-b53a-8eb647519e0f" name="2s" type="WaitStart">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <narrative>It is needed to let IE respond to the previous navigate action</narrative>
    <display x="-60" y="-45" w="30" h="30" />
    <groupid>ddb7d93e-1817-4d88-99a1-7639b8e6fa77</groupid>
    <choices />
    <timeout>[Wait XS] * 2</timeout>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="b32e859c-de87-49be-af60-8614c310b9d1" name="Time Out" type="WaitEnd">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="-15" y="15" w="30" h="30" />
    <onsuccess>f14ac644-b807-4a4d-bf2f-250a6159cdeb</onsuccess>
    <groupid>dd9c94a3-1a29-4b7d-9570-bb5b39a4a221</groupid>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="525c998c-dd0d-40a4-bdf0-fc3b94816f3e" name="HTML Doc" type="WaitStart">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="-75" y="15" w="30" h="30" />
    <groupid>dd9c94a3-1a29-4b7d-9570-bb5b39a4a221</groupid>
    <choices>
      <choice reply="True">
        <name>HTML - HTML (HTML) Check Exists</name>
        <distance>30</distance>
        <ontrue>0a02670f-0fc9-429b-8817-d08250e9cb32</ontrue>
        <element id="8f3babb6-a5d1-49c1-b771-b2c93198ebe4">
          <elementparameter>
            <name>wPageAddress</name>
            <expression>[Parent URL]</expression>
            <datatype>text</datatype>
            <comparisontype>Wildcard</comparisontype>
          </elementparameter>
        </element>
        <condition>
          <id>CheckExists</id>
        </condition>
        <comparetype>Equal</comparetype>
      </choice>
    </choices>
    <timeout>[Wait XL]</timeout>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="f14ac644-b807-4a4d-bf2f-250a6159cdeb" name="HTML Document is not loeaded in time" type="Exception">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <display x="45" y="15" />
    <exception localized="yes" type="System Exception" detail="&quot;HTML Document is not loeaded in time.&quot;" />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="8050e231-8753-47dd-8044-c1cb98582209" name="Not Found" type="WaitEnd">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="-15" y="135" w="30" h="30" />
    <onsuccess>707dec3d-5f31-421a-944e-f1dbfef3b8fb</onsuccess>
    <groupid>65179067-ff34-48f6-98d8-4807b7f97f58</groupid>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="f642c18e-277e-4af6-8a75-4ebdf4090f0e" name="Loaded" type="WaitStart">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="-75" y="135" w="30" h="30" />
    <groupid>65179067-ff34-48f6-98d8-4807b7f97f58</groupid>
    <choices>
      <choice reply="True">
        <name>HTML - Loaded Check Exists</name>
        <distance>30</distance>
        <ontrue>fdfe5291-d54c-482a-87fa-b387430d3deb</ontrue>
        <element id="91543f0d-e580-4c28-836f-7d101d35d6c9" />
        <condition>
          <id>CheckExists</id>
        </condition>
        <comparetype>Equal</comparetype>
      </choice>
    </choices>
    <timeout>[Wait XL]</timeout>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="707dec3d-5f31-421a-944e-f1dbfef3b8fb" name="Loaded Element Not Found" type="Exception">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <display x="45" y="135" />
    <exception localized="yes" type="System Exception" detail="&quot;Loaded Element Not Found&quot;" />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="d96ec66e-4310-4416-a253-c416509adf6d" name="CreateLoadedElement" type="Data">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="-195" y="15" w="150" h="30" />
    <datatype>text</datatype>
    <initialvalue xml:space="preserve">function CreateLoadedElement(){var LOADED = document.createElement("ChromePageLoadedForBluePrism");document.head.appendChild(LOADED);}</initialvalue>
    <private />
    <alwaysinit />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="0a02670f-0fc9-429b-8817-d08250e9cb32" name="Insert JS Page Loaded" type="Navigate" interval="[Wait XS] / 4">
    <subsheetid>55725c0e-f413-4bd7-8949-b2e1524868cd</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="-45" y="75" />
    <onsuccess>f642c18e-277e-4af6-8a75-4ebdf4090f0e</onsuccess>
    <step>
      <element id="8f3babb6-a5d1-49c1-b771-b2c93198ebe4">
        <elementparameter>
          <name>wPageAddress</name>
          <expression>[Parent URL]</expression>
          <datatype>text</datatype>
          <comparisontype>Wildcard</comparisontype>
        </elementparameter>
      </element>
      <action>
        <id>WebInjectJavascript</id>
        <arguments>
          <argument>
            <id>fragmenttext</id>
            <value>[CreateLoadedElement]</value>
          </argument>
        </arguments>
      </action>
    </step>
    <step>
      <element id="8f3babb6-a5d1-49c1-b771-b2c93198ebe4">
        <elementparameter>
          <name>wPageAddress</name>
          <expression>[Parent URL]</expression>
          <datatype>text</datatype>
          <comparisontype>Wildcard</comparisontype>
        </elementparameter>
      </element>
      <action>
        <id>WebInjectJavascript</id>
        <arguments>
          <argument>
            <id>fragmenttext</id>
            <value>"window.onload = CreateLoadedElement();"</value>
          </argument>
        </arguments>
      </action>
    </step>
  </stage>
</process>
```

**STEP 4:**

Copy the following code (two Variables) to the **Initialise** page:

```
<process name="__selection__Software - Chrome Template" type="object" runmode="Exclusive"><stage stageid="e7282352-6604-49eb-bb62-d57e9c2a8f68" name="Wait XL" type="Data"><loginhibit /><display x="-195" y="15" w="150" h="30" /><datatype>number</datatype><initialvalue>60</initialvalue><alwaysinit /></stage><stage stageid="9648a1bf-1642-467d-b8d9-c6b351165cbd" name="Wait XS" type="Data"><loginhibit /><display x="-195" y="45" w="150" h="30" /><datatype>number</datatype><initialvalue>1</initialvalue><alwaysinit /></stage></process>
```

**STEP 5:**

In the following picture, stages marked with '**H**' map to the created element: '**HTML - Html Root**', while the item marked with '**L**', map it to the other created element: '**HTML - Loaded**'.

[image]

**STEP 6:**
Check your error count to make sure there are no errors.

**STEP 7:**
The page will be working (if Chrome is not messing up with it's security settings), when a page already exists in the browser, as this requires an existing document loaded, but it is normally the case.